# how to remove an image from folder via mysql statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have a blog when I delete the blog post I want the script to delete the image in the folder the folder path is .  ../images/    table name is:  **postImages** and is in FROM **blog_posts_seo**

```
//show message from add / edit page
if(isset($_GET['delpost'])){ 

    $stmt = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM blog_posts_seo WHERE postID = :postID');
    $stmt->execute(array(':postID' => $_GET['delpost']));

    //delete post categories. 
    $stmt = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM blog_post_cats WHERE postID = :postID');
    $stmt->execute(array(':postID' => $_GET['delpost']));

    header('Location: index.php?action=deleted');
    exit;
```

Above is my script which deletes the post via postID and then deleted the Categories but i need to add on delete image with unlink image

Comment: `unlink("path to image/imageName.jpg")`

Comment: So you will have to `SELECT` that data from the `postImages` table and loop the resultset coding a delete like @MasivuyeCokile showed you above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the photo path from the database before you delete it, and use [unlink](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) to delete the file.

```
// select the path from database
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT photo_path from photos WHERE postID = :postID');
...
$src = "/pathToImages/images/";
if(isset($photoPath) && file_exists($src . $photoPath)) {
  unlink($src . $photoPath); 
 }

// delete post and photos from database
....
```

Comment: the image is stored in ../images .   but the postImages only displays the file name example .  test.jpg does not display the path

Comment: @JoeWilson Just concatinate the path to images folder, I've edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

This function is just reliable one because attacker may delete any file from the database.

the php for the code must be

```
if (array_key_exists('delete', $_POST)) {
$filename = $_POST['delete'];
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    unlink($filename);
    echo 'Successfully Deleted';
}
else 
{
    echo 'Problem occured';
}
}
```

You can use this PHP code to make the file delete just print

you can use the reference websites - www.w3schools.com
- wiki.php.net
-w3resources.com